# Angular JS Permissions Check

Tags: angularjs, permissions

Have a long list of items for some of which the user has permissions for some of them don't. How can I check if the user has permission for specific item?
I can load the permissions in the controller and then when I iterate trough the list in ng-repat call a method to check if for that item I have permission - the item is in the permissions array - loaded before.
What I have seen trying this approach is that because of the two way data biding this takes a long time - the check is executed even when the user is doing something else on the screen - clicking a button - interacting with the controller. What will be the best method to implement this?

Comment: In general you shouldn't send data to the client, if the user does not have permission to see those data. I recommend checking it on the server side. Check which role the authenticated user has and only send data back which the user is permitted to see.

Comment: Good idea, I am actually checking on both places in the front end side and  in the back-end - stored procedure in the DB. The interesting part is the angular one way data binding optimization, currently I am doing it using the two way mechanism

Answer (score 0):

I update my user (->permissions) only on app start or route changes.
With this, I get no performance problems in my central method

```
$rootScope.authService.hasPermission(roles)
```

which only checks the result, so js has nothing to calculate in template.

Answer (score 0):

Just use memoization technics. Permission checks should not change very often (I guess after login form and after logout). So, you can do something like:

```
var memoize = require('lodash.memoize')
var hasPermission = memoize(service.hasPermission)
```

If you want to clear cache just call

```
hasPermission.cache.clear()
```

I used this approach on my projects using [CASL](https://github.com/stalniy/casl) and it works quite fast